# Flow Rate inside of a blood vessel

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The velocity of blood flowing in a blood vessel of radius $R$ is $v(r) = k(R^{2}-r^{2})$, where $r$ is the distance from the center of the vessel and $k$ is a constant.

Let $v(r)$ be the velocity of blood in an arterial capillary of radius $R = 2\times 10^ {-5}$ m.

Use Poiseuille's Law with $k = 10^{6}$ m/s to determine the velocity at the center of the capillary and the flow rate.

For the record, the initial velocity is $0$ and flow rate is represented by the formula: $2\pi \displaystyle \int_0^R kr(R^2-r^2) \, \mathrm dr$.

I found that the velocity is at the center is 0.0004 m/s but I can't seem to find the correct flow rate. I keep getting the result $1.00530965\times 10^{-12}$.

Thanks.

[work included](https://sphotos-b-ord.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/1240414_10151638772528590_1781807342_n.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

When representing numbers in scientific notation, you use $10{\text{^}}$ or E, not both.

With a radius of $2 \cdot 10^{-5}$m, the area is $4\pi 10^{-10}m^2$.  If your velocity were constant, you should have a flow rate of $4 \cdot 10^{-4}4\pi10^{-10}\approx 5.03\cdot 10^{-13}m^3/sec$  Since the flow goes to zero at the walls, it should be even lower.  If you show your work we may be able to find the problem.

Added:  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20%28%282%2a10%5E-5%29%5E2x-x%5E3%29%20from%200%20to%202%2a10%5E-5) agrees with your evaluation of the integral.  Your result now shows the average velocity is half the central velocity, which is correct.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. And I 'll post an image of the work that I have gone through thus far.

Comment: I found a factor $4$ coming from the radius, which I corrected.  I think your value is correct, though different from what you originally posted.